# Angular2 component doesn't have class reference after redirect via router from callback

Tags: redirect, angular, router

Hi I have set up this plunkr to demonstrate the problem I have.
https://plnkr.co/edit/tO4xbD15A3FvjpaGw6J5?p=preview

This is the main part of the code that does the redirect after the successful login. I can't refer to the "isLoggedIn" variable as this is in the callback function...

```
loginLaunch() {
console.log("authentication.ts:loginLaunch()");
let authProperties = AUTH_PROPERTIES; 
authProperties.immediate = false;
// Sign the user in, and then retrieve their ID.
let ga = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
let router = this.router;
let redirect2 = this.redirectUrl;
ga.signIn(authProperties).then(function() {
    console.log("authentication.ts:loginLaunch() - logged on:"+ ga.currentUser.get().getId());
    //this.isLoggedIn=true;
    // Redirect the user
    console.log("authentication.ts:loginLaunch() - logged in now, redirect to "+redirect2);
    router.navigate([redirect2]);
}); 
}
```

The example works with a file "app/authentication.ts" and I have put in two versions:
"app/authentication.ts.works" and a
"app/authentication.ts.worksNot"

The first one is a dummy authentication (doesn't really ask you for a password) and the second one uses Google authentication.

The problem I have is this. With the google authentication (using a promise / callback) the Angular2 component after the redirect doesn't have the reference to the component class. In this case, it should show the details of "label" after the user logs in. But it doesn't. Do you have any idea what is going on here?

If you copy the content of "app/authentication.ts.works" into "app/authentication.ts" then the application works as expected: the label information is shown on the Component1 page after logging in.

Any help is appreciated.

Helmuth

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `function ()` because this causes `this` to point to the function instead of the class.

Use instead arrow functions `() =>` which retains the scope of `this`:

```
ga.signIn(authProperties).then(() => {
```

Your code has several uses of `function ()`. I suggest you to replace them all, except when the behavior of `function ()` is intended (rare cases).

Comment: Thanks. Didn't make much of a difference... but will look into it and make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out what the problem was (updated the plunkr example). Instead of calling the router.navigate from the "authenticate.ts" directly, I had to call it using the "zone.run()" to ensure the current zone picked up changes in unrelated child components (is my guess...):

```
    this.zone.run(()=>{
        router.navigate([redirect2])
    });
```